# "At advanced level"

Tags: sentence-construction

Instead of saying "She teaches students whose level of English is advanced," I can say:

> 1. She teaches advanced students.
> 2. She teaches students at (an) advanced level.
> 3. She is teaching advanced-level students.

But is my choice of article wrong in the second sentence?

Comment: Note that in a English or Welsh cultural context  "at Advanced level" might by understood to mean "for the A-level qualification"

Comment: As @JamesK puts it, if I heard the OP's sentences 1, 3, I would promptly feel compelled to ask "advantage on what?" even though I am a non native speaker.

Comment: Advanced and advantaged may sometimes be misheard, but they are pronounced differently, and have very different meanings  (advantaged means rich)

Comment: @JamesK Thank you for the correction. I really tried to mean "advanced" but ended up in writing "advantage". Sorry for the OP and thank you James.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your article choice is right and correct.

It is just fine to say: *"She teaches students **at an advanced level [adverbial meaning - how she teaches students]**"* which means *"She teaches students to reach/achieve an advanced level"* but not necessarily.

But if you wanted to imply that "students" are advanced, giving them a sort of general opinion or more precisely *"students who are at an advanced level"*, I would recommend saying:

> "**She teaches** [ well, far, fairly, quite - should you look for *additional emphasis* ] **Advanced English students/learners.** *( general opinion + type + noun* - as you pointed out, your first choice "...whose...", at least for me, could be a bit verbose )"

Tense-wise, your third sample would express that *"she is teaching students now"* . In other words, if you want to make a clear statement, simply use *"the present simple/tense"* and avoid using the present continuous.

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply. Thus, "She teaches advanced English students" and "advanced-level  students" means her students are advanced. If she teaches students to reach an advanced level I should use "She teaches at advanced level." Is "a" optional and can I use "the" instead?

Comment: @Antonia A You are welcome! :) *An* indefinite article is not optional here, in actuality it is optimal. Also, I don't think *"the"* is appropriate here as we are taking about instances, but not specificity.